# How can I use XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Using Xpath, how do I extract the text of the 'p' in the 'description'?

```
<item>
            <link>http://spor.haber7.com/futbol/haber/2335589-ispanya-avrupa-sampiyonu</link>
            <guid>2335589</guid>
            <pubDate>Sat, 20 May 2017 00:24:00 +0300</pubDate>
            <category><![CDATA[Futbol]]></category>
            <title><![CDATA[Ä°spanya Avrupa Åampiyonu]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[<a href="http://spor.haber7.com/futbol/haber/2335589-ispanya-avrupa-sampiyonu" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.cdn.haber7.com//haber/haber7/thumbs/2017/20/ispanya_avrupa_sampiyonu_1495229064_1854.jpg" /></a><p>Ä°spanya, normal sÃ¼resi 2-2 berabere sona eren final maÃ§Ä±nda Ä°ngiltere'ye penaltÄ± atÄ±ÅŸlarÄ± sonucu 4-1 Ã¼stÃ¼nlÃ¼k kurarak kupanÄ±n sahibi oldu.</p>]]></description>
        </item>
```

These are the lines of code I wrote. I have arranged my lines of code as follows, following the recommendation of @romanperekhrest. But it still does not work.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, re


class aliSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "aksam_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://www.aksam.com.tr/cache/rss.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '/rss/channel/item'

        baslik_SELECTOR = './/title/text()'
        icerik_SELECTOR = './/description/text()'
        link_SELECTOR='.//link/text()'
        tarih_SELECTOR='.//pubDate/text()'


        for brickset in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR):
            tree = ET.parse(brickset.xpath(icerik_SELECTOR).extract_first())
            root = tree.getroot()
            desc = re.search(r'<p>([^<>]+)</p>', root.find("description").text).group(1)

            yield {
                'baslik': brickset.xpath(baslik_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'icerik': desc,
                'link':   brickset.xpath(link_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'tarih':brickset.xpath(tarih_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            }
```

Comment: take a look at [extract_unquoted()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.XPathSelector.extract_unquoted)

Comment: I apologize, I have examined the page on the link you gave me. I know your answer is written there, but I do not understand. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

***XPath*** (>=1.0.4) solution:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/item/description, "<p>"), "</p>")
```

XPath result:

```
Ä°spanya, normal sÃ¼resi 2-2 berabere sona eren final maÃ§Ä±nda Ä°ngiltere'ye penaltÄ± atÄ±ÅŸlarÄ± sonucu 4-1 Ã¼stÃ¼nlÃ¼k kurarak kupanÄ±n sahibi oldu.
```

Used functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before

---

***Python*** 3.x solution with [***xml.etree.ElementTree***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, re

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
desc = re.search(r'<p>([^<>]+)</p>',root.find("description").text).group(1)
print(desc)
```

The output:

```
Ä°spanya, normal sÃ¼resi 2-2 berabere sona eren final maÃ§Ä±nda Ä°ngiltere'ye penaltÄ± atÄ±ÅŸlarÄ± sonucu 4-1 Ã¼stÃ¼nlÃ¼k kurarak kupanÄ±n sahibi oldu.
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How can I use this code in the python programming language?

Comment: @DavutDURGUN, it was an answer, not a comment. I've added python solution, check it

Comment: I'm working in Python 2.7, I guess these codes are giving an error.

Comment: @DavutDURGUN, for Python 2.7: replace `print(desc)` with `print desc`. Otherwise, post the error message

Comment: I've added the codes I wrote to the subject I've opened. Please check back and tell me your opinion?

Comment: @DavutDURGUN, I see some problems there.  In particular, this lines `tree = ET.parse(brickset.xpath(icerik_SELECTOR).extract_first())
            root = tree.getroot() .... ` should not be in loop, cause tree should be built on the whole xml document, but not on each element in loop